# What is the custom RequestCultureProvider lifecycle in ASP.NET Core MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, lifecycle, .net-6.0

I'm writing a small web app using ASP.NET Core 6 MVC with Razor pages. I'm currently working on localizing the web app and writing a custom `RequestCultureProvider` implementation that uses a separate field added to a custom user profile model to determine the culture and UI culture.

However, since I don't want to query the database for every request, I'd like to have some in-memory caching in place, probably in a form of a simple private `Dictionary<string, string>` mapping the user ID's to culture.

A question I have related to this: what is the lifecycle of a custom `RequestCultureProvider` in this case? In other words, can I have that primitive cache as a local variable or should I create yet another class that would serve as a caching service and make it a singleton?

The initialization in `Program.cs` looks like this:

```
// Localization options
var supportedCultures = new[] { "en-US", "ru-UA" }; // TODO: Move to config
var localizationOptions = new RequestLocalizationOptions()
    .SetDefaultCulture(supportedCultures[0])
    .AddSupportedCultures(supportedCultures)
    .AddSupportedUICultures(supportedCultures)
    .AddInitialRequestCultureProvider(new UserCultureProvider());

app.UseRequestLocalization(localizationOptions);
```

I can also provide the code for the `UserCultureProvider` if needed, but I'm not sure it's relevant to the question.

Comment: Looks like I also have an issue described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69131341/asp-net-core-5-mvc-httpcontext-user-not-authenticated-in-custom-cultureprovide, so maybe I'm also doing something wrong in the setup.

Comment: Does your problem resolved?

Comment: The problem I've described in the comment - yes, I needed to explicitly await on the auth method inside the call to determine the culture. However, my original question about the lifecycle still stays.